# Dreamweaver Database connection to phpmyadmin not working

Tags: dreamweaver

So, I realise there are a lot of threads with this topic already but I have went through every single one of them (Majority of them are the exact same) and nothing seems to work.

**As a note, I am using a trial version of Dreamweaver cc 2015, and I am using WAMPSever.

So, I have a testing server working. The problem I am having is creating a MySQL connection from Dreamweaver to phpmyadmin. The error that persists is the:
HTTP ERROR CODE 404 File not found. Here are some possible reasons for the problem:
1) There is no testing server running on the server machine.
2) The testing server specified for this site does not map to the. Verify that the URL in the prefix maps to the root of the site.

I have moved the MMHTTPDB.php and mysql.php into the right folder. I have also selected the server model to be PHPMYSQL.

This is my site:

[image]

This is the testing server:

[image]

I am fairly new to using Dreamweaver but I have not been more frustrated with anything in my entire life.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I was unable to post more than 2 links, so here is the URL for 2) 
http://localhost:8888/phpmyadmin/_mmServerScripts/MMHTTPDB.php URL

Comment: I don't know Dreamwaver at all, but phpMyAdmin is an application for you to manage your MySQL or MariaDB database. You shouldn't be pointing Dreamweaver at phpMyAdmin to access the database. I don't know what it's asking for with the "Web URL" setting, but it's definitely not phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

I was in a similar situation a week ago and spent sleepless nights trying to find a solution. Like you, I have never been frustrated as I was by this. Finally, I had to downgrade my XAMPP version because I learnt that if you're using the deprecated server behaviors in Dreamweaver, they won't work with the latest version of XAMPP.

I downloaded an older version and I am okay now.